# hibernate equivalent of javax.persistence.* annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In below java entity bean class, we are using @Id and other annotations. They are from the javax.persistence.* package.

I read the SO and other forums, every one say that, JPA is specification/rule set and Hibernate is one of the JPA implementations.If that is the case, how come JPA is providing the these classes/interfaces such as @Id (Generator interface).

If I understand correctly, JPA itself provides the capability to support ORM without using Hibernate?

also, I would like to know
1) the Hibernate annotation classes corresponding to these JPA annotations -@Id.
2) for javax.persistence.* package, do we need use Hibernate-Annotations jar? or they are from JPA specific jar, if so please help me understand the package name.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  public Employee() {

  }
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  public Integer getId() {
  return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
  return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations are basically interfaces without implementation. JPA is a specification for an API, it is not an implementation. The JPA API can be accessed via annotations. JPA says what should be done, not how it should be done.

The specific implementation, like Hibernate or EclipseLink, will use the annotations at compile time and at run time to implement the functionality. Thus the annotations are markers for the implementation on where to hook in its own code or how to treat certain objects. So there is no need for corresponding annotations in Hibernate when using JPA. The annotations should be the standard annotations so Hibernate can recognize them.

If you use vendor specific annotations you are using a different API. This different API may even use the same implementation but you access it in a different way. Using a vendor specific API with vendor specific annotations is useful when it provides functionality that JPA doesn't deliver and that you need. Especially before JPA 2.0 Hibernate offered a lot more than the standard so it was not uncommon to use the vendor specific API.

Comment: Thanks @his, I got it. not sure why SO is not provided provision to accept all correct answers!!:)

Comment: SO's idea is about the one correct, best answer. Sometimes this principle doesn't work out so well. But you can always upvote the other helpful answers.

Comment: you are right. But if user like me who has less reputation has no way to upvote!!

Answer (score 2):

JPA is the specification that says: an entity class is a class annotated with @javax.persistence.Entity. It must have one field or getter annotated with @javax.persistence.Id.

Hibernate implements what the specification says. So it uses the standard JPA annotations. If it used proprietary annotations, it wouldn't respect the specifications. And if the specification didn't define any annotation, every implementation would have to define its own, proprietary annotations, and it wouldn't be possible to write JPA code that would work on various implementations of the standard.

Comment: thanks @JB Nizet, I got it. Could you please help me with question 2) in my updated post:2) for javax.persistence.* package, do we need use Hibernate-Annotations jar? or they are from JPA specific jar, if so please help me understand the package name.

Comment: but in this example we are not using hibernate right, do we? my example can be considered as purely JPA example?